# Eclipse: icons in drop down

Tags: eclipse

I've been looking up icons here:

http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-icons.htm

but I'm not clear what some of these icons are in the drop down menu for Java:

[image]

The obvious ones are:

- S: Static
- F: Final
- empty blue diamond: default field (I think)
- filled red square: private method
- filled yellow diamond: protected method
- filled green circle: public method

but what's the:

- red blob between and below S and F to the left of `ADD_TODO_ITEM_REQUEST`
- solid blue triangle next `onActivityResult`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`red blob` is `private field`.
`solid blue triangle` is `default method (package visible)`

Source & Ref.:  http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-icons.htm